# Attribute or Array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need to find out, if a function parameter in my php-script is a regular string attribute or an array.

How would I do that?

```
if(gettype($array) == "string"){return $array;}
```

doesn't work.

is there an error in this line? I'm new to php.

Comment: Read the manual -> [**is_array**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) ?

Comment: thx - I am under some pressure.
Got assigned to the project  and only started with php yesterday. #_#

Comment: To summarize: `echo (is_array($array) ? 'is an array' : 'is something else');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there are bunch of options. It might be safer to specifically check for both desired. PHP has methods to check for each of its  types.

```
if(is_array($array)) {
  // array
}
elseif( is_string($array)) {
  // string
}
elseif( is_object($array)) {
  // object
}
// could also do is_float, is_number, is_boolean, is_resource
```

Comment: Thank you, but I only need to know, if it is an array, since I want to use `implode()` on it.